# how to combine icontains filter so it searches from one field and another at the same time

Tags: python, django, filtering

```
def search(request):
    queryset_list = Listing.objects.order_by('-list_date').filter(is_published=True)

    if 'keywords' in request.GET:
        keywords = request.GET['keywords']
        if keywords:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(description__icontains=keywords)
        if keywords:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(realtor__name__icontains=keywords)
```

I would like to be able to search 2 things at the same time. for example if description contains "big" and `realtor__name` doesn't I would like to still see the the object with big and same for `realtor__name` even if description doesn't have it I would like to get it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need the `or` operator

**Ex:**

```
from django.db.models import Q


if keywords:
    queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(Q(description__icontains=keywords) |
                                         Q(realtor__name__icontains=keywords))
```

Comment: Please accept ans(tick symbol) if it solved your problem. Thanks